How to make a fixed navigation menu transparent when scrolling?
I've been researching how to make the navigation bar transparent but I can't find which mistakes I've done. Currently the menu does not change at all could anyone please give me an example of the code I would need to use in order to make it transparent whenever I scroll down.
I am trying to create a fixed navigation menu that will become transparent when the user scrolls down the page. I used the following code:
I expected the menu to gradually become transparent as the user scrolls down, but it remains the original color. Also I tested my code in different browsers to ensure consistent behavior.
I've tried adding the following CSS:


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');

  function toggleMenuTransparency() {
    if (window.scrollY > 0) {
      menu.classList.add('tranparent')
    } else {
      menu.classList.remove('transparent');
    }
  }
  window.addEventListener('scroll', toggleMenuTransparency);
});
.menu {
  width: 100%;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #f00, #00f);
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.menu .transparent {
  background: linear-gradient( 45deg, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.8));
}
HTML here please!



Together, this means that the following styles will only apply to elements within the menu when the transparent class is added to them
and here it is on JavaScript:
In JavaScript, I use document.querySelector('.menu') to select the menu and add the transparent class when the scroll passes a certain value.

Please put your code in a demo using the editor. See [ask]. You'll need to include some HTML.

At a glance, you're referencing a child relationship in your CSS with .menu .transparent, but your script implies a same-element situation, as .menu.transparent. Try removing the space in your CSS.

Your JS can be down to:  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { window.addEventListener('scroll', function() { element.classList.toggle('transparent', (window.scrollY > 0)); }) })

Also it won't gradually change color... it will just snap from one color to the next.

As for the "same color", 0.8 alpha is very close to the original full value, it's barely noticeable.

How about a CSS only option - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/wvOoZOM

@Paulie_D your codepen works for me in Chrome, but not Safari.

Without the asked for HTML on this we are doing a bit of guessing here. Please provide that.  I made a snippet to get you started here

Scroll event listener is not that efficient and avoid using it. Use Intersection Observer API instead.
Here is my solution.
I used the Intersection Observer API to add or remove a CSS class based on whether the .dummy element is in view. This approach is more efficient than using a scroll event listener because it avoids unnecessary calculations and improves performance. Play around with the Intersection Observer API and CSS to optimize the result as per your need.


const navEl = document.querySelector('.menu');

const dummyEl = document.querySelector('.dummy');

function toggleMenu(entries) {
  const [entry] = entries;
  if (entry.isIntersecting) {
    console.log('Intersecting');
    navEl.classList.remove('transparent');
  } else {
    console.log('Not intersecting');
    navEl.classList.add('transparent');
  }
}

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(toggleMenu, {
  root: null,
  threshold: 0,
  rootMargin: '0px',
});

observer.observe(dummyEl);
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>Title of the page</title>
  <script defer src="script.js"></script>

  <style>
    .menu {
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      height: 80px;
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
      z-index: 1000;
      background: linear-gradient(45deg, #f00, #00f);
      padding: 10px;
      transition: all 0.2 ease-in-out;
    }
    
    .menu a {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: white;
    }
    
    .menu.transparent {
      backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
      background: linear-gradient( 45deg, rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.8));
    }
    
    main p {
      font-size: 40px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="menu">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  </nav>
  <main>
    <div class="dummy"></div>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent finibus volutpat pretium. Donec vestibulum laoreet dignissim. Pellentesque ut lorem a nisi blandit volutpat. Vivamus dictum lectus quis elit pretium congue. Morbi ut imperdiet orci. Vestibulum
      ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Nullam vehicula dictum elit et condimentum. Phasellus ultrices imperdiet nibh, vel consectetur tellus lobortis id. Nunc facilisis venenatis ante, a feugiat risus. Sed faucibus
      sit amet nisi eu mattis. Ut ut lorem in ipsum viverra eleifend. Donec sit amet ullamcorper est. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed in auctor tellus. Aenean vel sagittis magna. Morbi euismod fringilla sem, et lobortis orci gravida imperdiet. Nullam
      ut sapien eu tellus pellentesque commodo vitae a risus. Praesent vehicula porta felis. Morbi eu consequat libero. Pellentesque pellentesque luctus pretium. Etiam eget posuere sapien. Donec aliquet orci eu consectetur commodo. Sed non leo id mi commodo
      semper dignissim tristique risus. Etiam vel est imperdiet, bibendum eros non, facilisis purus. Ut lacinia pretium dolor quis venenatis. Etiam sed faucibus libero. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempus nulla vitae
      magna euismod sollicitudin. Nullam eu lacus vitae leo ornare consectetur vitae vel dui. Nam maximus lacinia velit in mollis. Donec mauris velit, consequat eget vulputate at, pretium sed est. Aliquam mattis erat sit amet nunc venenatis, nec iaculis
      nulla imperdiet. Donec eget diam vulputate libero vulputate aliquet sit amet et dolor. Vestibulum dictum nisi mauris, ut mattis erat vestibulum non. Integer fermentum dapibus leo, quis dignissim odio ullamcorper et. Maecenas id mollis tortor. Aliquam
      vestibulum enim velit. Quisque placerat vestibulum ligula quis sodales. In mattis non velit et ultrices. Sed sapien dolor, viverra in est in, dapibus tristique purus. Nulla ac placerat eros, nec eleifend urna. Mauris et lacinia lacus, a porta nibh.
      Vestibulum porttitor, justo accumsan scelerisque convallis, eros augue vulputate lorem, at blandit felis nisi ut dolor. Aenean laoreet, nisl non euismod venenatis, justo nisi faucibus metus, id feugiat lacus augue quis urna. Sed at dolor tortor.
      In cursus quam ac nisl malesuada finibus. Donec neque augue, auctor finibus sollicitudin at, sagittis vitae augue. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia curae; Sed venenatis ipsum diam, ut tempus nisi venenatis
      et. Donec malesuada interdum imperdiet. In tincidunt est non suscipit volutpat. Nulla iaculis suscipit justo, non malesuada felis bibendum ut. Nulla sed nisl dolor. Nunc ipsum nisl, egestas vel purus consectetur, venenatis congue augue.
      <p>
  </main>

</body>

</html>



